# in Web API 2 how to accept simple types as post parameter along with Route parameter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Hi after some struggle I am finally got past the angular js hurdle to pass the proper parameters to my server, but the web api 2 service fails to accept it.

below is the sample code

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/bids")]
public class BidsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{quoteId:long}/accept")]
    public HttpResponseMessage AcceptQuote(long quoteId,[FromBody] string remarks)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, quoteId);
        return response;
    }
}
```

if you notice i have both the route parameter and also a post parameter of type sting. When I post using fiddler with the following:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:81/api/v2/Bids/101/accept? HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic a2lyYW5AYWJjc2hpcHBlci5jb206a2lyYW5AYWJjc2hpcHBlci5jb20=
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/shipper/
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0; EIE10;ENUSWOL)
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
Content-Length: 40
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache


{"remarks":"Accepting this as the best"}
```

or use angularjs function:

```
    function acceptQuote(quoteId, accept_remarks, fnSuccess, fnError) {

        return $resource("/api/v2/Bids/:id/accept", { quoteId: "@id"},
            { "AcceptQuote": { method: "POST", isArray: false } })
            .AcceptQuote({ id: quoteId }, { remarks: accept_remarks }, fnSuccess, fnError);
    }
```

returns the following error:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"remarks":["Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}}
```

i expected that using `[FromBody]` was sufficient to pass the simple types as post parameters, any ideas to what else I am missing  here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FromBody] is working a bit differently. Please, check this [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). If you'd like to get the string `[FromBody] string remarks`, then your body must look like:

```
"Accepting this as the best"
```

Not a JSON. On the other hand, if the body contains the JSON, the most natural way how to consume that with ASP.NET Web API, is via the Entity/Object. So, we can create this

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string remarks { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller action should look like this:

```
[Route("{quoteId:long}/accept")]
public HttpResponseMessage AcceptQuote(long quoteId, MyObject myObject)
{
    var remarks = myObject.remarks;
```

Comment: Thanks again, the link you provided was really helpful to understand whats going on in the background.